# Is it possible to create buttons in matplotlib so that I can do things as in GUI interface?

Tags: python, matplotlib

is it possible to create buttons in matplotlib, so that I can do things as in GUI interface? if it is possible, how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

An alternative way to create interactive graphics with matplotlib is with the new [Quibbler package](https://github.com/Technion-Kishony-lab/quibbler/issues).

This tool automatically makes any matplotlib graphics interactive, as well as making widgets like Sliders, Buttons etc interactive without a need to write callback functions.

See some examples in the [Quibbler docs](https://quibbler.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Examples.html).

For transparency: I am one of the developers of Quibbler.